# genymotion icon is not shown in android studio

Tags: genymotion, android-studio

i want to use genymotion in android studio. i have installed genymoiton and oracle virtualbox. in android studio i went to: File> settings> plugins , and installed genymotion. i should say that, previously, i have create a virtual device in genymotion. 
the problem is: i expect that the genymotion icon to appear in android studio 
but: nothing appears

any help is highly appreciated...

Comment: Please vote for migration to Stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing Genymotion plugin and restarting Android Studio you should see the Genymotion device manager icon in the toolbar:

[image]

On newer Android Studio version the toolbar may be disabled or not fully shown. Make sure the toolbar is activated:  Menu **View** -> **Appearance** -> **Toolbar**

[image]

Additionally when you click the Genymotion icon the first time you have to manually specify the Genymotion installation directory, e.g. by default it should be this path:

```
C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion
```

Comment: as you said, i expect this icon, but it does not appear. i activated the toolbar in: Menu-> View->Appearance->Toolbar,  but unfortunately there is no genymotion icon yet. yes i previously specified this path for genymotion. actually i can access genymotion through search, but no there is no icon

Comment: @user324903 If the icon misses but the path can be configured then the plugin is correctly installed. You can manually add the icon by clicking right on the empty area of the toolbar and select "Customize menu and Toolbars" then search for "Genymotion" and add the icon.

Comment: in "Customize menu and Toolbars" im searching for "Gennymotion" but nothing is found. do you know where can i find it?

Comment: Make sure to upgrade to the latest Android Studio version 4.0 and reinstall the Genymotion plugin. Looks like something went totally wrong on your installation. Besides that the Genymotion plugin is not very useful, it just allows to start a Genymotion emulator which you can also do from the main Genymotion program.

Comment: actually after activating toolbar which you said, i update plugins and restart android studio, and the icon appeared. thanks a lot